# Error code convention?

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling

At the place where I used to work, our PHP developer set up a list with custom error numbers. We communicated over a REST interface (pure json).

Example could be (random):

- 100 User not authenticated;
- 200 Date not defined;
- 210 Parent code not defined;
- 300 Database transaction failed;

Etcetera, well you know; a long list.
The purpose was that I interpreted these errors at the client, and took care of the necessary front-end actions accordingly.

For a personal project, I would like to do the same, but I wonder if there are some conventions related to error codes.

Answer (score 0):

With a REST api, you should use the HTTP status code to indicate an error. Take a look at: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: What about custom codes for eg. database transaction failed? Is there some convention?

Comment: Generally you don't want to expose that type of information through the api. You want your API to abstract away the storage details. By passing information like database transaction failed through the API, you are violating that abstraction. In the case of a database error, I think you would want to return a 500 error (maybe another error code) and then log more specific information about that error on your server so you can recover it.

Comment: well i disagree with most of this, most API's i work with return usefull messages or codes; http status codes are for the status of the network connection not the API

Comment: You can certainly supplement the HTTP status code with more error information if you wish. However, this information can often be redundant and/or indicate too much detail about the implementation being passed to the user of the api (eg. database error messages). Take a look at Twitters API error codes, they use a combination of HTTP status codes and custom error codes to provide more information. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the standard HTTP status codes are the best solution. If you need to send more information, I suggest that you send a descriptive message with it ie (HTTP 401: "User not Authenticated")

If you start commonly needing error codes that don't fit into the standard HTTP status codes, you might be giving the client data that it doesn't really need. For something like a failed Database transaction, I would probably just return HTTP 500 and log the stack dump on the server. If you have access to the server, you can grab it from there. If you don't, then you probably don't have access to the database either,  so the information won't help.